# Difference between the persistent and cache directory in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand difference between cache (temporary) files created in `getCacheDir()` and usual (persistent) files created in `getFilesDir()`. In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) the main point was that cache-files are removed when the user deletes the app, but I thought that usual files had the same behaviour. If so, why were two similar entities implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misread the documentation. It mentions that both directories are cleared on uninstall, however it then goes on to say [referring to the cache directory]:

> although the files in this directory might be removed sooner.

So the difference is that you cannot rely on persistent files in the cache directory, they might be removed by the system.

---

In response to your comments, I think there's still some confusion, so let me clear some method definitions:

`getCacheDir` - used to store cache files. These might be deleted at anytime by the system, however they can live *longer* than the runtime of your app. In theory they could persist until the app is uninstalled.

`getFilesDir` - used to store persistent files. These should live as long as they're not cleared either manually by the user (by clearing the app data) or the app is uninstalled.

`File.createTempFile` - this simply creates an empty file with a unique file name with the specified prefix (if will also use a default extension `.tmp` and the default temporary directory if not specified otherwise). Note that there isn't a special type of temporary file, it behaves as a normal file, it's just a utility method for unique naming etc.

Comment: Ok, i've reconsidered documentation and your reply. I guess i mixed up these two subjects - temp files and cache directory. Correct if i'm wrong: first one is used when we want file to exist only in runtime for example (in opposite to persistent files), and second is platform convenient place for these files, which cleans up periodically (but for guarantees we should clear that files manually) , at the same time both persistent and temporary files are deleted when app is uninstalled, but temporary's lifetime more shorter?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by temporary files? Android only has the two concepts - persistent and cache. Persistent being for storing data and cache for storing temporary files for various purposes. Also the cache directory doesn't necessarily clean up periodically, I don't think the Android system guarantees that, it probably depends on the OEM.

Comment: Sorry for long-time answer. I meant Java`s temporary files, created by Java.io.File.createTempFile(). As for me, finally come to this: persistent files lifetime start app - to delete app; temporary start app - to Runtime end execution (or some intermediate delete call). And app deletion will clear both files. (Also from device app page we can separately delete specific files type). Overall first type files should be stored at getFileDir() and second at getCacheDir(). I'm i correct now?

Comment: I think you still are missing a couple of things, let me update my answer.

Comment: Ok, things got clearer now, thanks for reply.